# How do I mutate an array inside my state?

Tags: reactjs

I am keeping track of the birthday and need to change the state as the user types, but the issue is a new instance of my birthday array is created when the user types overriding the state. Any idea how to change the birthday index state i.e. when they enter a month position 0 will change, date position 1 will change, year position 3 will change.

```
this.state = {
  dob : ["", "", ""]
};



onInputChange(event) {
    const type = event.target.name;
    var dob = ["", "", ""];
    if(type == "month") {
      birthday[0] = event.target.value;
      this.setState({ dob });
    } else if(type == "date") {
      birthday[1] = event.target.value;
      this.setState({ dob });
    } else if(type == "year"){
      birthday[2] = event.target.value;
      this.setState({ dob });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is `onchange` of any value you are creating a new instance of dob, and replacing the value of state by that newly created `array`, instead of that copy the value of dob from state and then update the specific value, and put that `array` back to state, Write it like this:

```
this.state = {
  dob : ["", "", ""]
};

onInputChange(event) {
    const type = event.target.name;
    var dob = this.state.dob.slice();
    if(type == "month") {
      dob[0] = event.target.value;
    } else if(type == "date") {
      dob[1] = event.target.value;
    } else if(type == "year"){
      dob[2] = event.target.value;
    }
    this.setState({ dob });
}
```

Check the working `fiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/drffr0ww/

Comment: This doesn't work. This is what happens https://puu.sh/uc7tq/e8646eab30.png